# How do I initialize a class in Java, while the class I want to initialize will vary based on a variable?

Tags: java, object, oop

I'm trying to make a terminal program that will initialize a class based on input from the user. Is there a way that I can initialize a specific class using a String variable without cluttering up my program with `if` statements? Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

Terminal:

```
Which program would you like to run? Please type in lower case.
 - Room designer
 - Etc.

>
```

Code:

```
String answer = input.nextLine();
[answer] programToRun = new [answer]();
```

Is there a way to do this? I know that there is a way in Python using the `Globals` dictionary, so I'm confident there is a way, and that I just haven't been able to find it.

Comment: This is not clear. Can explain more?

Comment: @BasilBourque He probably wants something like if answer = a, then instantiate `new A()`, if answer = b, then `new B()` etc.

Comment: @Dominic Do those classes have something in common, like implementing the same interface, or extending the same class?

Comment: @Chaosfire they're both going to be managing files, just the format of the file will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to use the Factory pattern

```
interface Factory<T> {
  T createInstance(String param);
}

public class FactoryManager {
  private Map<String,Factory> factories;
  public void registerFactory(String type, Factory f) ... // add the key/pair to the factories map
  public Object createInstance(String s) ... // match the string to a Factory in the factories Map and call createInstance on it
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions about this

-- Edit --

Example:

```
public class Car {
  private make = null;
  public Car() {};
  public Car(String make) {
    this.Car();
    this.make = make;
  }
}

public class CarFactory implements Factory<Car> {
  public Car createInstance(String s) {
    return new Car(s);
  }
}

public class Bus {
  private make = null;
  public Bus() {};
  public Bus(String make) {
    this.Bus();
    this.make = make;
  }
}

public class BusFactory implements Factory<Bus> {
  public Car createInstance(String s) {
    return new Bus(s);
  }
}

public class MyFactoryManager extends FactoryManager {
  public MyFactoryManager() {
//All this actually should be in the base class FactoryManager so it doesn't need to be implemented in each FactoryManager.
    factories = new HashMap<String, Factory>(); 
    public Object createInstance(String s) { // This could be expanded with another parameter to be passed to the factory for object initialization.
      return factories.get(s).createInstance();
    }
  }
}

FactoryManager fm = new MyFactoryManager();
fm.reqisterFactory("car", new CarFactory());
fm.reqisterFactory("bar", new BusFactory());
Object car = fm.createInstance("car");
Object bus = fm.createInstance("bus");
System.out.println("Car is a " + car.getClass());
System.out.println("Bus is a " + bus.getClass());
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Factory pattern. Unfortunately, I'm not the most fluent with Java. Would you please help by giving more information?

Comment: @DominicMiller https://www.baeldung.com/java-factory-pattern

Comment: is `registerFactory` a method? In which case, should I expand it and use that map to tie it all together? I'm understanding a little bit, but I'm not exactly sure how to integrate it. @ControlAltDel

Comment: @DominicMiller yes, registerFactory is a method. I'm not sure what you mean by "expand it" but if you mean fill in the method so that it adds the type/factory pair into the map and to use the map in fulfilling `createInstance` in `FactoryManager`, then yes

Comment: I'm sorry, I know that I already selected this as the answer a long time ago, and I know it'll work, but I just can't implement it. Do you think I could have an example with comments explaining things? I appreciate your patience. @ControlAltDel

Comment: @DominicMiller In the model API I included with this question, you could alter `createInstance` to have it return a `Factory` (and return a Factory via `factories.get(s)`) instead of an Object. From there, you can create an object from the factory with Factory.createInstance. Does that help?

Comment: It opens up a new possibility, but I don't understand. What would classify as a Factory object for the `RegisterFactory()` method? The model shows Factory is an interface, and the factory pattern is simply a concept. Should I implement the interface in the other classes? And if so, how do I get it as an object?

Comment: Oops, meant to ping @ControlAltDel

Comment: @DominicMiller "What would classify as a Factory object for the RegisterFactory() method?" I already posted a link to a Java Factory Pattern example. "Should I implement the interface in the other classes?" Yes. "And if so, how do I get it as an object?" I really can't explain this better than I did in my post plus the link on factory pattern. Seeing that you still don't understand, you should try to seek out another source (school, online, etc) who can mayb

Comment: I just can't figure out what goes in the `Factory f` parameter for `RegisterFactory()`. I get type is the key for the key/pair but what will pass for `f` with `Factory` as a datatype?

Comment: Sorry it keeps removing it from the beginning of my comment @ControlAltDel

Comment: @DominicMiller I have updated my answer. Hopefully it answers your questions

Comment: This clears up everything! Thank you so much @ControlAltDel. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: This implementation of the factory pattern is quite complicated, but I suppose that's because the classes in the example don't have a common superclass. @DominicMiller if your classes do share a common base, then you could implement the factory in a simpler way. It's hard to tell, because you didn't show example code in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to create an instance of a class from a string using its no-args constructor (and crash if no such constructor exists):

```
package plugins;

public class ClassName {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Works as expected!";
    }
}


public class ClassByNameTest {
    @Test
    void createInstance() throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        String className = "plugins.ClassName";
        Object instance = Class.forName(className).getConstructor().newInstance();

        assert a.getClass().getName().equals(className);
        System.out.println(instance.toString());
    }
}
```

Following some kind of convention, for example implementing a common interface, you could call an entrypoint method to run arbitrary behaviour dynamically.

EDIT:
Despite the fact that this is technically no problem, ControlAltDels idea to use the factory pattern is the better way to solve this, especially because it decouples the user input from your actual class name.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Is there a way that I can initialize a specific class using a String variable without cluttering up my program with `if` statements? ..."*

You can use the *[reflection framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)* to instantiate a class via a *String* value.

You'll need to provide the fully-qualified name.

```java
Class<?> c = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
Object instance = c.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```